# Finding power series expression

Tags: power-series

Hi could anyone help me with this problem.   Use series to approximate the value of the following function to two decimal places. Integrate from 1 to 0 $\sqrt{1+x^4}$. I tried to differentiate the expression but I still could not change it to a form that allows me to express it as a power series.

Comment: I don't get it, $\int_0^1 \sqrt{1+x^4}\;dx$ is a number, not a function.

Comment: Sorry I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Well, to start with, consider the function $$f(t)=\sqrt{1+t}=(1+t)^{1/2},$$ and find its Maclaurin series. It shouldn't be difficult to find an explicit formula for the $n$th derivative of $f$ for all $n\ge0,$ and the coefficients of the Maclaurin series will fall right out of that formula.

Now, $\sqrt{1+x^4}=f(x^4),$ so you'll easily get a power series for your function that way, which you'll want to integrate from $0$ to $1$. Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT :**

The series expansion of [$(1+y)^{\large\frac12}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions) is
$$
(1+y)^{\large\frac12}=1+\frac12 y- \frac18 y^2+\frac1{16} y^3-\frac5{128} y^4+\frac7{256} y^5-\cdots
$$
then take $y=x^4$ and integrate it.